# Rig Veda sayings about pest control

Tags: rig-veda

Wikipedia says that Rig Veda mentions about pest control.

> The Rig Veda, which is about 4,000 years old, mentions the use of
>   poisonous plants for pest control.

Which excerpt of Rig Veda talks about pest control?

Comment: Most probably its a Neem tree, but if not a  poisonous plants it could also be cow dung or cow urine. Both having very good  pest repelling properties. Also its quite possible that  this is not  mentioned in core samhita section. Let us see. Hope we will come up with an answer.